# SetInterval so i looks like its spinning

Tags: javascript, setinterval

When the user press "Spin" the app loops thru the images and chooses a random image. I have to set an Interval so you can see the random images before it find the random one. So it look like it's spinning.

Here's the code:

```
var omzetteller = document.getElementById('omzet');
var omzet = 100;
omzetteller.innerHTML = omzet;

var afbeeldingArray = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png'];
var afbeeldingen = document.querySelectorAll('img');

function randomPlaatje() {
    var image = Math.floor((Math.random() * afbeeldingArray.length));
    var afb = "img/" + afbeeldingArray[image];
    return afb;
}

function krijgInzet() {
    var inzet = document.getElementById('inzet').value;
    return inzet;
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < afbeeldingen.length; i++) {
afbeeldingen[i].src = randomPlaatje();
}

function berekenOmzet(afb1, afb2, afb3){
        if(afb1 == afb2 && afb2 == afb3 && afb1 == afb3) { omzet += (krijgInzet() * 10); }
            else { omzet -= krijgInzet(); }
}

function gebruikPlaatje(){
    var afb1 = randomPlaatje();
    var afb2 = randomPlaatje();
    var afb3 = randomPlaatje();

    document.getElementById('img1').src = afb1;
    document.getElementById('img2').src = afb2;
    document.getElementById('img3').src = afb3;

    setTimeout(function() {
        berekenOmzet(afb1, afb2, afb3);
        omzetteller.innerHTML = omzet;
    }, 1000); // 1000 = 1 seconde

    setInterval(function() {
        randomPlaatje();
        clearInterval();
    }, 1000); // 1000 = 1 seconde
}

function start(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        gebruikPlaatje();
    }, 1000); // 1000 = 1 seconde
}

var spin = document.getElementById('spin');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');

spin.addEventListener('click', start);

reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
    omzet = 100;
    omzetteller.innerHTML = omzet;
});
```

Comment: What is the question or specific problem?

Comment: I need to setInterval images so it look like the slot machine is spinning. I have a loop and i think there need to be a setInterval at the loop so it looks like it's spinning the images before it sets one image.

Comment: Do you mean keep changing the images over and over for an interval? Still not clear what issue is

Comment: Note that `clearInterval()` needs an interval ID argument.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval

Comment: i tried this: var changeImage = function() {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < afbeeldingen.length; i++) {
afbeeldingen[i].src = randomPlaatje();
}};
setInterval(changeImage, 1000);